# Missing network settings in KDE

Tags: networking, network-manager, kde, settings

I installed the KDE desktop environment using `apt install kde-plasma-desktop`. The problem is that I don't have network settings in System Settings:

[image: network configuration settings window]

<sub>(source: [kde.org](https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.9/network-configuration.png))</sub>

Of course, I'm missing this from my System Tray as well.

How can I install these settings?

Comment: `kubuntu-desktop` installs everything (kde plasma; all apps and everything that comes with kubuntu).   i don't know what exactly installs network; usually I select from 'aptitude' search if I want only parts; or install all then remove any 'bloat' that worries me.

Comment: But I would like to know how to install it, I don't want to install kubuntu-desktop and tons of bloat. I like "clean" KDE.

Comment: which i why i mentioned 'aptitude' & why i like it.  it lets you view whats in the kubuntu-desktop package (47 packages, 138 recommends); which I use as a menu & `sudo apt-get install` in another window what I want  (or at least I used to; recent releases I just grab kubuntu-desktop & delete.  my comment wasn't intended as an answer; but an idea that may provide what you want...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Installing full Kubuntu Desktop is the way of achieving full desktop installation  with its complete features, but the package itself comes bundled with tons of default programs: `kubuntu-desktop` will install its own file manager, document reader, terminal emulator, etcm which is annoying to some people.

Aside from that, there is `kde-plasma-desktop` that offer plasma desktop with minimal installation. Unfortunately, the package doesn't include the kde's network manager while `kubuntu-desktop` does.

But the good news is, you can always install it manually.

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-nm
```

If the icon does not appear in your system tray, just logout and login.

Comment: This answer is missing how to activate the installed package, to make the related tray icon show.

Comment: @Akito is right. I had to logout and login to fix it but maybe there are other solutions. I've added this note into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-kde
```

Comment: This works but at the moment Ubuntu runs with Network Manager and not `wicd` so just installing the Network Manager's applet (`plasma-nm`) is a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure who answered this correctly.  Either Valerio Bozz or Liso

So I just downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.01 and installed it then installed KDE 5.24.6  as per instructions at https://computingforgeeks.com/install-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-linux/

I switched from gdm3 to sddm.  then rebooted and now have KDE 5.24.6.  However it did not install the Network manager for KDE.
As documented above I installed Network Manager for KDE with the following command.

user@hostname:path$  sudo apt-get install plasma-nm

That did install the Network Manager on the Panel in KDE 5.24.6
Thank you for your excellent advice.

Francis