Where in System Settings do I set a static IP for Kubuntu 22.04 LTS?
I am aware of a similar old post, but the solutions posted did not work in Kubuntu 22.04 LTS. Currently in my system menu, this is what appears under the tab for Network:

Here is a visual of the other options within the settings for Network currently:

However from this video showing Kubuntu 18, there is a tab for connection:

Is there a hidden config that must be enabled to allow this?

Have you checked "Connection Preferences"`?

See at: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-fixed-ip-address.html.en

@amar yes. Added gif for visual

@kyodake Correct, but for some reason the section is missing

See if this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/963847/missing-network-settings-in-kde

This question is similar to: Missing network settings in KDE. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please see https://netplan.io and https://netplan.io/examples.
